# What is the relation between Perspective, translateZ, rotate3d, and no. of faces

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, css-transforms

I am referring the [this post](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/carousel.html) for 3d transformations.

[image]

So I am trying to set the perspective property of `.container` dynamically such that the adjacent faces should appear perpendicular to front face like shown in below image with green lines.

[image]

Related code

```
.container {
  width: 210px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ( -288px ) rotateY( -160deg );
}

#carousel figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 186px;
  height: 116px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

I tried with different kinds of combinations, but it was partially correct as its working either with small no of faces or large no of face.
I know just that the perspective value is inversely proportional to no of faces.

```
perspectiveValue = translateZValue/noOfFaces;
perspectiveValue = translateZValue*rotationAngle/noOfFaces;
```

Please let me know if anyone knows about the relation between perspective, translateZ, rotate3d, and no. of faces. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone knows how can I ask any particular user for the help? because I can see the developer on SO who developed the above post, how can I communicate with him or link him to this thread?
@desandro can you please help.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for that? Because i'm not getting the problem.

Comment: @vinayakj it seems he has a [twitter account](https://twitter.com/desandro). At the bottom of the page there is a "Know someone who can answer?" part.

Comment: @Kaiido really thanks.. On his site he mentioned _not available for personal support_, so I am not sure about contacting him via other mediums as he may not like that.

Comment: @MaciejKwas [Here](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/carousel-02-dynamic.html), I want the face 2 & 9 be perpendicular to face 1, so if you set the perspective of `.container` to `perspective: 90px;`, it appears perpendicular, but if no of face changes this value needs to be calculated again and I am searching for the such formula.

Comment: @vinayakj: there is a very **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**-centric post on similar topic as well which I find interesting in a way that it explains nitty gritty details. **[Here](http://greensock.com/cube-dial-tutorial)** is the article. But then again, I am not exactly sure how would it help you because, as I said, it is a very focused solution using a **[number](http://greensock.com/draggable)** **[of](http://greensock.com/tweenmax)** **[products](http://greensock.com/throwpropsplugin)** from GSAP suite.

Comment: Thanks @TahirAhmed I looked into the post, it doesnt discuss much about perspective property and its relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your perspective point needs to be in the intersection between the two sides on the right and on the left

For the case that you post, this is

```
105 px * cos (40deg) = 80 px
```

Sorry - I made a stupid mistake, it's tan. The correct formula is

```
105 px * tan (40deg) = 88 px
```

The perspective point (the star) needs to be axial to the next sides, to the right and to the left. (the green lines). 
This way, you are looking from the indicated point (the star) and you see the right side fully in your direction (you are looking in the green line direction) - so this side is "collapsed". And the same for the left side .

So the pespective value is the dimension of the green arrow:

[image: diagram]

Further illustration (click to zoom)

[image]

Beatiful [code](http://vinayakjadhav.github.io/jR3DCarousel/) using this perspective posted by vinayakj

Comment: Tried `(width/2)* Math.cos(2*Math.PI/faces)`, not giving correct result, is there anything missing?

Comment: For 9 faces, `105 px * cos (40deg) = 80 px` correct but for 20 faces applied same formula it came out `105 px * cos (18deg) = 99 px` where expected was `34px ` at [Here](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/carousel-02-dynamic.html)

Comment: You are great.. thanks.. worked like a charm.. eligible for bounty tomorrow.. I had otherwise came to approximation by using `(translateZ/faces/2/2*Math.PI)*(angle/faces/2/2*Math.PI)+(translateZ/(angle)/Math.PI)`, kinda sin wave form..

Comment: So the green line intersection is the perspective point or something, can you please add some explanation too, bit confused..

Comment: I am not good enough drawing .. I have tried to make it clearer.

Comment: No problem.. I would _figure_ it out.. thanks though for the whole explaination.. appreciate your help.

Comment: OOPS ! I wanted to add a coment and added an answer..  I have added your link to the answer, I liked it.  ( But If you don't like it,  I will delete it)